# Button click trigger anchor tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of jquery tabs with hash anchor tabs.

I want to trigger the second tab '#second' when i click the submit button.

I used some solutions but doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#bt').click(function() {
   $('#ex').click();
});
</script>

<div id="tabs">
<ul id="tabbbs">
<li><a href="#first" id="ex"></li>
<li><a href="#second" id="ex"></li>
<li><a href="#third"></li>
</ul>

 <div id="first" >
 <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
 </div>
 <div id="second" >
 <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
 </div>
<div id="third" >
 <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
 </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="bt" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">
  <?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?>OK</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple same `id` is not correct when you are trying to deal them with jQuery:-

BTW You can do like below:-

```
$('#bt').click(function() {
   $('ul li a[href="#second"]').click();
});
```

Note:- jQuery library needed to be add before your script code to make it work.

***Just a demo example(when you click either link or button class will added):-***

```js
$('#bt').click(function() {
 $('ul li a[href="#second"]').click();
});

$('a[href="#second"]').click(function() {
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
color:green;
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="tabbbs">
<li><a href="#first" id="ex">Click1</a></li>
<li><a href="#second" id="ex">Click2</a></li>
<li><a href="#third">Click3</a></li>
</ul>

 <div id="first" >
 <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
 </div>
 <div id="second" >
 <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
 </div>
<div id="third" >
 <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
 </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="bt" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">OK</button>
```

Comment: i have v2.0.0 of jquery which one is recommended

Comment: This worked perfectly...Also, i am curious to know if it's necessary to use $(this).addClass('active'); because it worked even without this.

Comment: @SandeepTete  i just show you an example. ha ha. Means think how can i show you that my code worked or not. It's just an example

Comment: Oh, understood i got it!

Comment: @SandeepTete  glad to help you buddy :):)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with tab index also:

```
$('#bt').click(function() {
   $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 1 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on anchor tag so first of all, you need bind click event on anchor tag then you fire a click event on button click. Like below method

```js
$(function(){

$('#ex').click(function() {
   console.log('Hello clicked!');
});


$('#bt').click(function() {
   $('#ex').click();
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="tabbbs">
  <li><a href="#first" id="ex">Hi</a></li>
  <li><a href="#second" id="ex">Hello</a></li>
  <li><a href="#third">By</a></li>
  </ul>

   <div id="first" >
   <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
   </div>
   <div id="second" >
   <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
   </div>
  <div id="third" >
   <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
   </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="bt" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">OK</button>
```